# Propositional Equivalence-Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, equivalence-relations

$$ p ∧ ((¬p ∨ q) ∧ (¬q ∨ p))$$ is it a contradiction?
I have to prove that the statement is a contradiction.But my answer is $p$. I couldn't find out   my mistake.

Comment: I think it is neither: when p is false, the expression is false, but when p is true, it is q (if I didn't make any mistakes).